# ActiveRecord find starts with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Really simple question - how do I do a search to find all records where the name starts with a certain string in ActiveRecord. I've seen all sorts of bits all over the internet where verbatim LIKE SQL clauses are used - but from what I've heard that isn't the 'correct' way of doing it.

Is there a 'proper' Rails way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would highly recommend the [Searchlogic](http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/searchlogic) plugin.

Then it's as easy as:

```
@search = Model.new_search(params[:search])
@search.condition.field_starts_with = "prefix"
@models = @search.all
```

Searchlogic is smart enough, like ActiveRecord, to pick up on the field name in the `starts_with` condition.  It will also handle all pagination.

This method will help prevent SQL injection and also will be database agnostic.  Searchlogic ends up handling the search differently depending on the database adapter you're using.  You also don't have to write any SQL!

Searchlogic has great documentation and is easy to use (I'm new to Ruby and Rails myself).  When I got stuck, the author of the plugin even answered a direct email within a few hours helping me fix my problem.  I can't recommend Searchlogic enough...as you can tell.

Answer (score 117):

If you're looking to do the search in the database then you'll need to use SQL.

And, of course, you'll need to do the search in the database otherwise you need to load *all* the objects into Ruby (which isn't a good thing).

So, you will need something like

```
MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => ["field LIKE ?", "#{prefix}%"])
```

where `prefix` is a variable with the string you're looking for.

In Rails 3.0+ this becomes:

```
MyModel.where("field LIKE :prefix", prefix: "#{prefix}%")
```

Comment: The wildcard % should be at the end if you're searching for something that starts with the prefix.

MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => ["field LIKE ?", "#{prefix}%"])

Comment: Is there anyway to do this and also protects against `%` character injection?

Answer (score 10):

I don't want to write a scope every time I want to see if a specific column starts_with a prefix.

```
# initializers/active_record_initializers.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  # do not accept a column_name from the outside without sanitizing it
  # as this can be prone to sql injection
  def self.starts_with(column_name, prefix)
    where("lower(#{column_name}) like ?", "#{prefix.downcase}%")
  end
end
```

Call it like this:

```
User.starts_with('name', 'ab').limit(1)
```

Comment: This could also go in `ApplicationRecord` if you are using it as an abstract parent.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer:  I am new to Ruby and Rails, and I am still trying to learn the Ruby Way to do things, but I have been coding for more than half of my life, and professionally for a decade.  DRY is a concept with which I am very familiar.  Here is how I implemented it.  It is very similar to narsk's answer, which I think is also good.

```
# name_searchable.rb
# mix this into your class using
#   extend NameSearchable
module NameSearchable
  def search_by_prefix (prefix)
    self.where("lower(name) LIKE '#{prefix.downcase}%'")
  end
end
```

And then in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend NameSearchable
  ...
end
```

And then when you want to use it:

```
User.search_by_prefix('John')   #or
User.search_by_prefix("#{name_str}")
```

One thing to call out:

Traditional relational databases aren't extremely good at satisfying these kinds of queries.  If you are looking for a highly responsive implementation that will not kill your databases under load, you should probably use a solution that is tailored to the purpose instead.  Popular examples include Solr or Sphinx, and there are many others as well.  With this implementation, since you DRY, you could substitute the implementation with a separate indexer in just one place and you would be ready to rock.

Comment: Larry, I removed the P.S. where you asked people to up vote your answer because it's your first one (on a 3 year old question btw). If they like it, they will up vote it, no matter how many you have already given.

Comment: it seems to me that you could inject SQL into this one. Say `prefix` came from something like a search form, i could enter `something' OR 1 --` into that form. This would then list ALL the entries. This is pointed out in the guides, as well: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

Answer (score 5):

Very much like the above answer, but if you're using ActiveRecord...2.1 or greater, you could use a named scope which would allow you to use this "finder" on records retrieved thru associations:

```
class User
  named_scope :with_name_like, lambda {|str|
    :conditions => ['lower(name) like ?', %(%#{str.downcase}%)]
  }
end
```

Used like:

```
User.with_name_like("Samson")
```

(returns all users in your database with a name like "Samson".

Or:

```
some_association.users.with_name_like("Samson")
```

Users off that association only with a name like "Samson".

Comment: An interesting phenomenon has occurred.  You said you "like the above answer", but you were referring to an answer that is no longer the one directly above your answer.  Perhaps in the future, it would make more sense to refer to the answer by the author instead of the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's 2012 I thought I'd throw in this update to narsk's answer.

`named_scope` became simply `scope` a while ago so the example becomes

```
class User
  scope :name_starts_with, lambda {|str|
    :conditions => ['lower(name) like ?', "#{str.downcase}%"]
  }
end
```

Note I removed the first `%` from  narsk's solution as the OP is asking for a 'starts_with' not a 'contains' match.

Now you can do things like

```
User.name_starts_with("b").each do {|bs| puts bs.inspect}
bob = User.name_starts_with("bob").first

… etc
```

Note that scopes *always return collections*, never individual results.  That threw me when I was first starting out with AR and I still manage to forget that every now and again.

Comment: I guess the first part of your code should be `class User scope :name_starts_with, (lambda do |str| {:conditions => ['lower(name) like ?', "#{str.downcase}%"]} end ) end`

Answer (score 1):

Very terse syntax for the same thing might be:

```
Model.where(field: ('prefix'...'prefiy'))
```

This renders:

```
WHERE ( field >= 'prefix' AND field < 'prefiy')
```

This does the job as *'prefiy'* is the first string alphabetically not matching the *'prefix'* prefix.

I would not use it normally (I would go for squeel or ransack instead), but it can save your day if for some reason you have to stick to hash syntax for the queries...