# Rails filter Alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some articles and I want to filter them alphabetically

One selection on the view will be All Letter, so A-Z
How would I filter the articles A-Z

Another selection would to be sort them by letter

So if the user selects `A` `B` or `C`

It would show only the articles starting by `A` `B` or `C`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [ActiveRecord find starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251345/activerecord-find-starts-with). Also you can add separate `first_letter` field to your model and save first letters to this field. It will make your search faster.

Comment: This doesnt work as it interferes with my ransack search forms

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you're using `ransack`, you can do:

```
Article.search(:name_start => "A")
```

to get all of the articles with names starting with "A".