# ActiveRecord many to many should I make another table to hold the relation information?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rdbms

I have `albums` and `artists` tables that should relate as many to many: each album can be owned by multiple artists and each artist can have multiple album. But I need to know whether the artist is the main artist or just a contributor.

Currently I just use `artists` column in `albums` table to hold artists id in semicolon separated strings (format: 3;6;343;56;1). The main artist's id should appear first, the rest is just contributors.

Currently I access artist's contribution in an albums by query with `.where` and `LIKE` keywords. Then filter the array result to exclude prefix (artist id), based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251518/1137814) answer.

```
@albums_ = Album.where("artists LIKE :prefix", prefix: "%#{params[:id]}%")
@albums_contribute_to = @albums_.select { |album| !album.artists.start_with?("#{params[:id]}") }
```

Is there any more effective way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Played around with it for a little bit, the big idea was to put some additional information on the join table (in my example, I call it `primary`). And then read the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) to figure out how to tell `ActiveRecord` to use them.

```
# setup active record
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:'

# some tables (migrations / schema)
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:artists) { |t| t.string :name}
  create_table(:albums)  { |t| t.string :name }
  create_table :appearances do |t|
    t.integer :artist_id
    t.integer :album_id
    t.boolean :primary, default: false # <-- join table specifies who is primary
  end
end

# some models
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances
  has_many :albums, through: :appearances
end   

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  # three associations to appearances
  has_many :all_appearances,                                   class_name: 'Appearance'
  has_many :primary_appearances,  -> { where primary: true  }, class_name: 'Appearance'
  has_many :featured_appearances, -> { where primary: false }, class_name: 'Appearance'

  # three associations to artists
  has_many :all_artists,      through: 'all_appearances',      source: 'artist'
  has_many :primary_artists,  through: 'primary_appearances',  source: 'artist'
  has_many :featured_artists, through: 'featured_appearances', source: 'artist'
end

# some artists
dre  = Artist.create! name: 'Dr. Dre'
dogg = Artist.create! name: 'Snoop Dogg'
slim = Artist.create! name: 'Eminem'

# some albums
weed = Album.create! name: 'The Chronic 2001',
                     primary_artists:  [dre],
                     featured_artists: [dogg, slim]

show = Album.create! name: 'The Eminem Show',
                     primary_artists:  [slim],
                     featured_artists: [dre]

# it understands the associations
weed.all_artists.pluck :name      # => ["Dr. Dre", "Snoop Dogg", "Eminem"]
weed.primary_artists.pluck :name  # => ["Dr. Dre"]
weed.featured_artists.pluck :name # => ["Snoop Dogg", "Eminem"]

# might be nice to add similar scoped associations to get from Artist to Album
weed               # => #<Album id: 1, name: "The Chronic 2001">
  .primary_artists # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Artist id: 1, name: "Dr. Dre">]>
  .first           # => #<Artist id: 1, name: "Dr. Dre">
  .albums          # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Album id: 1, name: "The Chronic 2001">, #<Album id: 2, name: "The Eminem Show">]>
  .last            # => #<Album id: 2, name: "The Eminem Show">
  .primary_artists # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Artist id: 3, name: "Eminem">]>
  .first           # => #<Artist id: 3, name: "Eminem">
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Looks complicated. I'll take try it first.

Comment: Given that one album can have at most one main artist, the primary column in appearances table is redundant. And I am afraid it is not the most efficient design for the given problem. This problem can be solved using HABTM(creating a join table only without creating a corresponding model) only. The main artist of the album can be stored inside an extra column(e.g. primary_artist_id) on the albums table.

Comment: @Ankush I didn't realise until you mentioned it. Yeah, know I feel the primary column is redundant. I end up using this solution because I though it will be flexible for me if I need another information regarding the relation of album and artist.

Answer (score 3):

It is typical case for using joined table. If you want to create that kind of relationship. What you are doing will only create problems in the long run as you will have to hold that information in memory, which is also slow.

In ruby on rails that relation would like something along this lines:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :album_artists
end

class AlbumArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, through: :album_artists
end
```

If you would like to avoid doing that with ruby on rails you have to implement custom query but the rules are the same, you have to create some kind of joined table.

Comment: I think about this previously. Will research it again.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Joshua and Przemek, it's an easy solution. here is how to use it:

```
class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
  # has attribute "primary"
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances
  has_many :albums, through: :appearances
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances
  has_many :artists, through: :appearances
end

# create album with 2 artists
Album.create(
  name: "foo_bar",
  appearances: [
    Appearance.new(artist: Artist.create(name: "foo"), primary: true),
    Appearance.new(artist: Artist.create(name: "bar"))
  ]
)

# list artists
album = Album.first
album.appearances.order("piramary desc").each do |appearance|
  puts "#{appearance.artist.name} #{appearance.primary? ? "(Primary)" : ""}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pasha. I accepted the first answer because he posted it first.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you need a separate model that joins the `Album` and `Artist` one. So you can use the `has_and_belong_to_many`(HABTM) method that is coming from `ActiveRecord` and is used for *transitive many to many* relations. You will also need a table that joins the 2 models and you can easily create one with a migration.

I highly recommend you to read this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/master-many-to-many-associations-with-activerecord/). It will be really helpful for you.

Comment: I also encounter this topic in the rails documentation. I also read that article before. Will consider some of the answers. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think HABTM isn't a proper option here. OP also wants to know who is the main artist and who is a contributor. So, it is good to have a separate model with additional column (like `primary` in previous answer) for tracking this.