# Searching for specific characters in user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my house table I have a postcode for each house.
I also have an index view for my housing table that contains a table which contains headings such as 'Name', 'Address', 'State'. I was looking to integrate a text_field_tag that would allow user's to input the 9 digits of a postcode in order to filter the table to only show the house with that postcode. However, I also want the user to be able to input the first 4 digits of their postcode e.g. '7644' and it would display all houses that begin with '7644' e.g. two records one with the postcode of the '76444-5645' and '76443-123'. Ideally I would apply logic through my '@search' variable within my houses controller. However I am up to any ideas or tips.

In order to instantiate the house model I would use @house = House.all

I'll be honest I don't know where to begin with this. I have arel_sql in my system so I assume that would be used to query for the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your models/controllers are defined but you're probably looking for the SQL operator [`LIKE` + '%'](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), which allows you to search for a pattern in a given column. Example:

| LIKE Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%' | Finds any values that start with "a" |

---

Assuming you're using ActiveRecord and your model is `House`, it wouldn't event need to instantiate all houses. Your code would look something like this:

```rb
postcode = '7644'
@houses = House.where('postcode LIKE ?', "#{postcode}%") # this returns where the postcode starts with '7644'
```

[another similar SO answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251518/10349618)

Comment: This was great help, I definitely will use this method of finding the correct records. Is there a way to map what the user's input e.g. instead of postcode being set already. You would allow users to enter in the postcodes.

Comment: Maybe set @postcode to the :postcode params when the user hits search? Then this could be added to your query above e.g. houses = House.where('postcode LIKE ?', "#{postcode}%")

Comment: Yes! I assigned it to a variable in the example just to illustrate.